# Как найти слово в поле из букв?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть идеи? Возможно поиск пути в графе?

> Первая строка входных данных содержит слово, которое вам нужно найти на поле. Длина слова от 1 до 25 символов. Следующие 5 строк содержат по 5 символов — поле филворда. Размер поля всегда 5 на 5. Выведите Y или N в зависимости от того, нашлось слово или нет. Буквы в слове могут располагаться как угодно, кроме как по диагонали

Ввели:

```
WORD
W R D Y M
F O H H H
N L K W O
R R R R R
A B B C D
```

Вывели: Y

Comment: Что уже сделали вы? Почему вы решили, что за вас должны писать код?

Comment: Этот вопрос чем-то принципиальным отличается от https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972989/?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сложная задача. Что за алгоритм?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972989/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

Comment: @gil9red, только тем, что на вопросы требующие правки невозможно дать ответ ;)

Comment: Не код. По-вашему быстрое возведение в степень или решето Эратосфена все тоже должны написать сами, без получения готовой идеи? Мне нужно не готовое решение, а идея алгоритма, или хотя бы нужную тему.

Comment: @ВикторЯмщин, присутствует ли слово `WORD` в приведенном примере? Иными словами - может ли слово располагаться `Г-образно`?

Comment: Да, может быть и квадратным или П-образным.

Comment: Может ли одна и та же буква использоваться более одного раза? Например, для примера в вопросе, `BCDRRC` должно вернуть `Y` или `N`?

Comment: Да, может повторяться.

Comment: Я вот думал, может как то через BFS решить можно.

Comment: Не надо создавать одинаковые вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Обычный обход графа. Я бы использовал DFS. В следующую вершину идём только если нам подходит такая следующая буква. В качестве массив used используем трёхмерный массив с третьим измерением - индексом буквы в искомом слове.

```js
var a = [
  "       ",
  " WRDYM ",
  " FOHHH ",
  " NLKWO ",
  " RRRRR ",
  " ABBCD ",
  "       ",
]

var s = "WORD"

var used = a.map(x => [...x].map(x => Array(s.length)))

var di = [0, 0, 1, -1], dj = [1, -1, 0, 0]
var path = []

function dfs(i, j, k=0) {
  if (a[i][j] === s[k] && !used[i][j][k]) {
    used[i][j][k] = true
    path.push({i, j})

    if (++k === s.length) return true

    for (var q=0; q<4; ++q) {
      if (dfs(i+di[q], j+dj[q], k)) {
        return true
      }
    }
    
    path.pop()
  }
}

ALL: for (var q=1; q<a.length-1; ++q) {
  for (var w=1; w<a[q].length-1; ++w) {
    if (dfs(q, w)) {
      console.log(path.map(({i, j}) => `(${i}, ${j})`).join("\n"))
      break ALL
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: А что делать, если есть два варианта с подходящими двумя подряд буквами, а в одном третья не верная? Мы же ищем элементы, совпадающие с буквами в слове только через один

Comment: @ВикторЯмщин, так ведь dfs будет все варианты обходить пока не найдёт.

Comment: Да, но он ищет путь, не учитывает подходит нам следующая вершина или нет, где мы будем хранить вершину на которой мы «остановились»?

Comment: И ещё, чтобы реализовать DFS нужен список смежности, как его можно составит для такой задачи?

Comment: @ВикторЯмщин, не нужен. Перед переходом проверяешь его допустимость.

Comment: @ВикторЯмщин, хм.. нюанс. А может одна буква использоваться несколько раз во вхождении?

Comment: Да, может....,,

Comment: Ну вот классический DFS, которому меня учили, не очень понятно как сделать так, чтобы между буквами были компоненты связности.

Comment: n = int(input()
adj_list = []
visited = [False] * n
component = [-1] * n
num_components = 0

def dfs(v):
    component[v] = num_components
    visited[v] = True
    for w in adj_list[v]:
        if visited[w] == False:
            dfs(w)

visited = [False] * n
for v in range(n):
    if not visited[v]:
        dfs(v)
        num_components += 1

Comment: Связность здесь очень простая - ребро есть, если любая из координат отличается на 1. В явном виде граф строить не нужно, метки посещения тоже ни к чему, раз можно несколько раз использовать.

Comment: @MBo, метки нужны, а то вместо O(n**3) получишь O(n!). С повторами как раз отлично подойдёт как я описал. Без повторов было бы сложнее, но как вариант вообще их в самом конце отсекать.

Comment: Координаты отличаются на один, это да, но очень сложно составлять рёбра, ведь непонятно самотёков главное- как реализовывать проверку под слово, во-первых она разная для разных позиций, а во-вторых, как поставить для DFS условие, ведь нам как-то нужно будет возвращаться к вершине, если элемент например в позиции через два не подошёл.

Comment: @ВикторЯмщин, ещё раз: 1. Не надо составлять рёбра, надо написать обычный цикл по 4 элементам и if на букву. 2. Рекурсивный dfs сам возвращается к вершине.

Comment: Я так и не понял. Можете написать?

Comment: @ВикторЯмщин, написал.

Comment: Спасибо. Что такое di и dj?

Comment: @ВикторЯмщин, массивы.

Comment: Имею ввиду, для хранения чего нужны

Comment: @ВикторЯмщин, четырёх сдвигов. Всё ж в коде видно. Они нигде не изменяются.

Comment: а точно вспомнил